# What is XMLHttpRequest's life cycle? When will the XMLHttpRequest be destroyed?

Tags: ajax

When is XMLHttpRequest destroyed?

I just wrote the simple function below, and `xmlhttp` has been sent successfully, but `responseText` isn't sent to the function `SetStringinDiv()`. The variable `str` is empty and the variable `location` has value.

I have no idea how to fix it, and I don't know what the keyword for this problem is, either. If this kind of question already exists, please tell me how to find it or what the keyword is.

```
<script>
function foo(){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var str = xmlhttp.responseText;
            SetStringinDiv("div1", str);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "uri", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<script>
function SetStringinDiv(location, str) {
    document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = location;
    document.getElementById("str").innerHTML = str;
    if (document.getElementByID(location) == null) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += ">> error, can not find the div, "
                + location + "\n";
    }
    document.getElementByID(location).innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for xmlhttp.status != 200 and print out an error. Print out the readystate and status on each call to onreadystatechange. I think you will see an error message in statusText.

These days it is recommended to not use the onreadystatechange callback. I use the code below. Note that if the server does not respond and does not close the connection that your request won't timeout for quite some time (2-5 minutes) - either in your code or that below. If it is sitting there, shut down the server. You will get an immediate error response then.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  done = function(response) {
    callback(cache[uri.split('/').pop()] = cache[uri] = response);
  };
req.open("GET", uri + ".lispz", true);
req.onerror = function(err) {
  done({
    uri: uri,
    error: err
  });
}
req.onload = function() {
  return (req.status != 200) ? req.onerror(req.statusText) : done(run(req.responseText));
};
req.send();
```

Comment: or you can set a different timeout on your request

Comment: well, if i dont use the function SetStringinDiv(), I can get the responseText by the document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
I just wonder why i cant use another function to do this with error detecetion, after all, it is not usual to get error message when editing web page in eclipse
And, thanks for your recommand, i will take it into consideration when developing a web sit

Comment: my problem has solved. because of stupid spelling problem. but I am really appreciate your answer. it is my first question in stack overflow. and thanks for your answer. I will accept your advice of coding modestly

Comment: Also where did you see that XHR.onreadystatechange is deprecated? You may've  been abused by the `document.onreadystatechange` event ?

Comment: XHR.onreadystatechange was necessary when it was the only method that would work with IE. I do remember reading, somewhere, that it was not the recommended method now that there are callbacks for error and load. But, you are correct - it is not deprecated.